# How to make menu close when next/previous links are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my [website](https://agencescoop-3cgaronne.pf5.wpserveur.net/) when i click the [magnifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJCdT.png) icon in the header to make a search, and i click previous or next page the menu-overlay element stay still an i can't click anything on my website, i guess the hide/show option is linked to the opacity.

I've tried to add this code but no change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const menucontent = document.querySelector(".content-type-menu");
const nomenuhere = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");

menucontent.addEventListener("click", () => {nomenuhere.checked = false;});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: Where is Loop icon. can you add image and explain exactly what you need

Comment: What do you mean by previous or next browser links? I couldn't see a previous or next link on the site.

Comment: i mean the previous or th next page

Comment: you will probably have to use hash parameters and your page needs to hide the menu when the hash param is not present

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak to your exact situation, as you don't have a lot of info to go on, but I'd solve it something like this:

```js
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

menuItems.forEach(menuItem => menuItem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  menuItems.forEach(menuItem =>
    menuItem.classList.add('closed'));
  e.target.classList.remove('closed');
}));
```

```css
.closed>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item closed">
    One
    <div>one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item closed">
    Two
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script.

```
// Select the toggle checkbox
const nomenuhere = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");

// Instantly set the state of the checkbox.
nomenuhere.checked = nomenuhere.defaultChecked;
```

It will reset the `checkbox` that shows your overlay.

When you search, click an item and go back the state of the checkbox state will be remembered. So the script here resets that state to its default state.